# Altering a Datomic schema using Datomisca

Tags: scala, schema, datomic

How do I add `isComponent` to a Datomic attribute using the Datomisca library?

In Datomic, I would do the following:

```
{:db/id :person/favorite-food
 :db/isComponent true
 :db.alter/_attribute :db.part/db}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I haven’t had time to add full support for schema alteration in Datomisca.

However, schema alteration is no different to any other transactions, so there should be no issue with building the transaction data that you describe above.

```
Entity.add(Namespace("person") / "favorite-food") (
  Attribute.isComponent -> true,
  Namespace("db.alter") / "_attribute" -> Partition.DB
)
```

What Datomisca *is* lacking is
[http://docs.datomic.com/javadoc/datomic/Connection.html#syncSchema(long)](http://docs.datomic.com/javadoc/datomic/Connection.html#syncSchema%28long%29)

But a datomisca Connection is just datomic Connection, so you can still access that underlying API. I will endeavor to add the new sync APIs in the near future.

For future reference, the google group is a good place to ask questions like these, as I’m more likely to notice them (a colleague noticed your question).
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/datomisca

Comment: This does not work for me: Entity.add takes a value that can be used as an entity id `AsEntityId` but the compiler tells me `Cannot convert value of type datomisca.Keyword to a Datomic entity id.` Am I missing something?